# something wrong with sendmessage API

Tags: vb.net

i try to make automatic key presser that make minimized game client do order for me while i work in other thing (aion game client) but nothing work here is the code i use please tell me what is wrong with it

```
    Const WM_SETTEXT As Long = &HC
    Const GW_CHILD As Long = 5


    Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal uCmd As Integer) As IntPtr
    Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr 'Int32
    Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" ( _
  ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
  ByVal wMsg As Int32, _
  ByVal wParam As Int32, _
  ByVal lParam As String) As Int32


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim hWnd1 As IntPtr = FindWindow("AIONClientWndClass1.0", "AION Client")
        Dim hWndR2 As IntPtr = GetWindow(hWnd1, GW_CHILD)
        SendMessage(hWndR2, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "h")
    End Sub
```

this is the code i use it must show window in the game when i click button1 , but nothing happen

i use visual studio 2013 and windows 10 64 bit

Comment: Are you trying to send a  h  keypress?

Comment: yes that what i try to do

Comment: and are you finding your pointers ? (hWnd1 and hWndR2)

Comment: i put break point on SendMessage(hWndR2, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "h")  hwnd1 give value but hwndr2 give me 0

Comment: ty guys i found my wrong :) ty

Comment: will share it the final code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my wrong

1. 1st my app need to run as administrator
2. 2nd have to set target cpu to 86x
3. 3rd i fixed my code , and here it is

   ```
   Const WM_SETTEXT As Long = &HC
   Const GW_CHILD = 5

   Const WM_KEYDOWN As Integer = &H100
   Const WM_KEYUP As Integer = &H101


   Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal uCmd As Integer) As IntPtr
   Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr 'Int32
   Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr,ByVal wMsg As Int32,ByVal wParam As Int32,ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr


   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       Dim _hndl As IntPtr = FindWindow("AIONClientWndClass1.0", "AION Client")
       SendMessage(_hndl, WM_KEYDOWN, &H55, 0)
   End Sub
   ```

&H55 is virtual key code = u